# Logitech K700 keyboard doesn't show up in /dev/input

Tags: raspbian, keyboard, input-device

With the [Logitech K700](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/logitech-k700) keyboard/mouse device plugged in to the raspberry pi, if I check `/dev/input/by-path` only a mouse shows up. I can still type in the terminal, but the keyboard device doesn't seem to be available.

Output with K700:

```
$ ls -l /dev/input/by-path
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Oct 23 17:27 platform-bcm2708_usb-usb-0:1.2:1.2-event-mouse -> ../event0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Oct 23 17:27 platform-bcm2708_usb-usb-0:1.2:1.2-mouse -> ../mouse0
```

I'm expecting to see something ending with `kbd` which is usually the case when a keyboard is plugged in.

Output with regular wired USB keyboard:

```
$ ls -l /dev/input/by-path
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Oct 23 17:27 platform-bcm2708_usb-usb-0:1.2:1.2-event-kbd -> ../event0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Oct 23 17:27 platform-bcm2708_usb-usb-0:1.2:1.2-event -> ../event1
```

Does anyone have any advice for getting the "keyboard" part of the K700 to show up?

Comment: Have you checked the output of `lsusb`?  What does the system see as devices?

Comment: @AwesomeUser nope, no solution yet

Comment: Maybe just try a different keyboard and see if that fixes anything.

Comment: @AwesomeUser Yes I am using a different keyboard now, and it works fine. That doesn't answer the question, though.

Comment: @krsteeve Have you tried using this keyboard with different OS's on your Pi? Have you tried it with a different computer to be sure the wireless and the USB connection are working?

Answer (score 1):

As this is a single controller (receiver) for multiple "devices" I'm suspecting you won't get them on their own - and the mouse is taking precedence in the way the Pi is seeing them, which is typical for mixed devices in my experience. I have a similar Microsoft keyboard which behaves in exactly the same manner.

They are integrated into the same unit so you cannot really test with just the keyboard, but I strongly suspect you won't be able to get the keyboard alone to appear on the list; You should however be able to access it using the standard input stream in programming (mine works just fine with my Java coding, as well as with that of others).

Without knowing the *reason* you need the keyboard on its own all I can suggest is using the mouse input as you have found it - it should read they keyboard portion just fine for most applications.